# 20.04.3 HP, Canon don't provide drivers. Is there a way around this?

Tags: printing

HP.LIP doesn't seem to work. Canon's driver site indicates no drivers available for the detected OS on several printers.

My old Epson Workforce 645 was great for a long time, but it needs replacing. I'm tired of printer roulette and how-to's for 20.04 that simply don't work. I followed on for a PIXMA MG3620, having bought that model because of the how-to, only to find it doesn't work.

What's causing this? Is there a reasonably inexpensive MFP that plug and plays with 20.04.3?

Answer (score 2):

Hardware recommendation are off-topic here at AskUbuntu.

But hardware recommendations are very much on-topic at the Linux Foundation's Open Printing site: https://openprinting.org/printers

Comment: Definitely, openprinting.org is where I check before buying a new printer.

Comment: I'll look there. My broader question is why printing/scanning suddenly stopped working. This is clearly something to do with the OS; it seems to have started with 20.04.2.

Comment: Maybe you intended to ask for troubleshooting help, but that's not how the question reads to other folks. If you want troubleshooting help, then your question should clearly ask for troubleshooting help instead of hardware recommendations. You can edit your question!

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my problem was that I was trying to work through the network printer discovery process. This was a dead end.

On the printers page, I used Add and then ignored the discovered printer. I typed in the IP address at the bottom. I then selected a driver from the list.

My printer is a Canon PIXMA MG3620, and I was able to find a driver for it.

I deleted the discovered printer entry.